# Pass values(Data) from one form to another form in J2ME using LWUIT library

Tags: java-me, lwuit

In J2ME i m using LWUIT library. I want pass data from one Form to Another Form.Is there any link or source code. Plz help me Friends,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Create a public static variable in the containing Form ; set its value to the data you want to be passed. Then call this static variable in the opened Form.